# CruiseControl.NET - Unused Note - <trunkURL>?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, continuous-integration

I'm just getting started with CruiseControl .NET (using the Manning Continuous integration book that just came out) and I'm having an issue with the configuration file.

I'm getting the error: "unused node" on the `<trunkURL>` tag.

The (slightly cleaned, using [ ] as placeholders) config file is below. Can anyone spot my error? I'm thinking/hoping it's something simple.

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
        <!-- This is your CruiseControl.NET Server Configuration file. Add your projects below! -->
            <project name="Build[Project]Lib">
                <workingDirectory>F:\CI\Build[Project]Lib\</workingDirectory>
                <artifactDirectory>F:\CI\Artifacts.Build[Project]Lib</artifactDirectory>
                <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet</webURL>
                <triggers>
                    <intervalTrigger initialSeconds="0" />
                </triggers>
                <sourcecontrol type="svn">
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Svn\svn.exe</executable>
                    <trunkURL>https://localhost:443/svn/[Solution]/trunk/src/[Project].Lib/</trunkURL>
                    <username>buildmaster</username>
                    <password>[Password]</password>
                </sourcecontrol>
                <tasks>
                    <msbuild>
                        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe</executable>
                        <projectFile>[Project].Lib.csproj</projectFile>
                        <buildArgs>
                            /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:minimal
                        </buildArgs>
                        <logger>F:\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
                    </msbuild>
                </tasks>
            </project>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

All the best,
Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer after some more search (of course, right after I post!)

At any rate, for future reference, the issue was that I was using `<TrunkURL>` when I should have been using `<TrunkUrl>`.